# Keep config file secure using github and Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, passwords, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using github (public) to keep track of my web app and about to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. Is there a good way to keep my config file secure which has RDS username/password? I have to add the file to git in order to push it to Elastic Beanstalk but this will make my password visible to everyone on github...? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Store them in the environment variables; don't hard code them in the repo.  Not familiar with Elastic Beanstalk in particular, but such platforms usually provides some configuration interface for them, such as [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managing.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct! Definitely keep your keys/passwords/credentials out of your committed codebase.

Elastic Beanstalk provides environment variables in the control panel for just this purpose. The official documentation can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-ruby

These environment variables can be edited through the Elastic Beanstalk UI.

You can then reference these variables in your `.yml` config files, e.g. `password: <%= ENV['PARAM1'] %>`.

Comment: Got it. it seems like I need to read through these two official docs for my python app. 

[Python Container Options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-python) and [Using an Existing Amazon RDS DB Instance with Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html). Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3128336 you can also set env vars using the CLI `eb setenv` or during create time `eb create --envvars`

Comment: With your advice, I was able to do this by adding env variables on eb and accessing them like os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']. Thanks a lot guys!